# Are there any other "special git commit messages" than [skip ci]?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops, cicd

I've seen `[skip ci]` added to commit messages in git to notify the DevOps platform to skip the CI pipeline for this commit. My guess is git probably doesn't care about [skip ci], but...

1. I'm wondering are there any other *commands* that can be added to commit messages?  Maybe [fixes #123] when a commit fixes an issue (on your task board), maybe others (but not sure what), just curious.
2. Is this syntax standardized, or is it highly dependent on the DevOps platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding metadata in commit messages goes back a long time. It's not unique to git, people have been embedding these kinds of references in TFVC and SVN and CVS forever.

The formats aren't standardized though, but they do often follow the same format. Unfortunately, there is no guarantee that a message that works on one platform will work on every other. Even on the same platform, you'll find differences between integrations.

> Azure DevOps is an example where the supported commands depend on whether your repo lives in Azure Repos, BitBucket or GitHub. Azure Boards and Azure Pipelines respond(ed) differently depending on the selected integration.

There are two kinds of command that spring to mind:

### 1. Commands that associate/link/interact with work

GitHub and Azure and Jira recognize special strings in your commit messages to automatically associate work (issue, user story, task) to a commit. Examples from the docs:

- [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/using-keywords-in-issues-and-pull-requests)
- [Azure DevOps on GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/link-to-from-github?view=azure-devops#use-ab-to-link-from-github-to-azure-boards-work-items)
- [Azure Repos commit message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/resolution-mentions?view=azure-devops) and [Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/auto-complete-work-items-pull-requests?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)
- [Jira Smart Commits](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/process-issues-with-smart-commits/)
- [Linear](https://linear.app/docs/github?tabs=206cad22125a#link-prs)

They all use a pretty common set of messages to link and close, but there is no guarantee they're going to be the same across all platforms.

### 2. Commands that influence Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery

GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines and BitBucket Pipelines and just about every other CI/CD platform out there will recognize special hints in commit messages to influence workflow runs.

These messages again aren't unique to Git, Azure Pipelines, for example, also supports building from TFVC or Subversion and will use these same strings for these other platforms as well.

- [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs)
- [Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/858#issuecomment-475768046)
- [BitBucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-skip-triggering-a-pipeline-build-using-skip-ci-label-1207188270.html)
- [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/docs/skip-build/)
- [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Skipping-a-build)
- Blog explaining the options for [GitLab](https://maxsmolens.org/posts/skipping-the-gitlab-ci-pipeline/) and the [official GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html).

Again you'll see that `[skip ci]` is pretty common, but each platform also has their own special keywords.

> Note that these commands might not even be universal on the same platform. `[skip ci]` hasn't worked in Azure Pipelines when connected to a GitHub Repo for a long time. This has since been fixed as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

1. Different platforms have different rules. For example
   [github](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/using-keywords-in-issues-and-pull-requests), [linear](https://linear.app/changelog/2022-02-03-github-commit-linking), [azure pipelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/858#issuecomment-475768046).
2. It totally depends on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

This `[skip ci]` syntax has nothing to do with Git (git(1)). It’s apparently from [GitHub Actions](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-08-github-actions-skip-pull-request-and-push-workflows-with-skip-ci/#:%7E:text=If%20any%20commit%20message%20in,visit%20the%20GitHub%20Actions%20community)

The only built-in Git commit syntax is whatever you have configured to serve as the comment syntax, which is by default `#` (ignore lines that begin with `#`). There are also some git-rebase(1) syntax like `fixup!` and `amend!` but those have to be opt into explicitly, so it has no meaning by default.

The conventional, most other-tool-agnostic way to signal metadata is with [trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) at the end of the commit message in its own paragraph:

```
Fixes: #42
```

But that can be configured to recognize the colon-less `Fixes #42` (or whatever it is) GitHubism since this *trailers* thing was introduced after it.

#### Subjective considerations

Git commit messages are forever. In that light one could ask if it is worth keeping such *ad hoc* third-party commands which really have nothing to do with the purpose of commit message which is supposed to tell what the commit is about. Things like `[skip ci]` because the CI is moody right now or `[ping @Paul]`[1] because he is at work today seems pretty ephemeral.

#### Notes

1. Made up